# How to group values within one list into multiple nested lists during iteration?

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I am having trouble figuring how to group every four values from list to then add as a nested list inside another.

Let's say I have the following list:

```
mylist = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7',
          'item8', 'item9', 'item10', 'item11', 'item12', 'item13', 'item14', 
          'item15', 'item16', 'item17', 'item18', 'item19', 'item12']
```

Now I want to group every four items inside this list into a nested list, but the nested list cannot be any longer than the maximum length of four.

i.e.

```
mylist = [['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'], ['item5', 'item6', 'item7',
          'item8'], ['item9', 'item10', 'item11', 'item12'], ['item13', 'item14', 
          'item15', 'item16'], ['item17', 'item18', 'item19', 'item12']]
```

How can I achieve such a result within a function where the data values are subject to change? In this function, I am specifying in my parameters that the amount of nested lists within the final result can be changed through an optional value. I am then specifying that each nested list cannot be longer than a specific length passed in the third argument that is also optional.

Arguments:

- values = The data that the function will alter into nested groups.
- num_of_lists = The maximum number of nested lists allowed inside the resulting list.
- max_list_num = The maximum number of values permitted inside a nested list.

How can I achieve the above result when `mylist` is passed into the `values` argument? Below is my current code.

```
def group_items(values, num_of_lists=5, max_list_num=4):

    grouped_lists = [[] for _ in xrange(num_of_lists)]
    counter = 0
    myvals = []

    for v in values:
        myvals.append(v)

    try:
        for item in grouped_lists:
            if len(item) < max_list_num:
                mygroup = myvals[0:max_list_num]
                if mygroup not in grouped_lists:
                    grouped_lists[counter].extend(mygroup)
            counter += 1
    except IndexError: pass
    return grouped_lists

print group_items(mylist, num_of_lists=5, max_list_num=4)
```

The above code is returning me this instead of the desired result:

```
>>> [['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'], [], [], [], []]
```

**(EDIT W/ ANSWER):**

Thank you Rakesh for the quick answer. Since this function was just a sample of my overall program that will be performing other tasks with the data, I needed to keep the code inside. I slightly modified his code and added it to my function (although I recommend his exact method since it is less lines of code):

```
def group_items(values, num_of_lists=5, max_list_num=4):

    grouped_lists = [[] for _ in xrange(num_of_lists)]
    counter = 0
    myvals = []

    for v in values:
        myvals.append(v)

    try:
        for item in range(0, len(myvals), max_list_num):
            nested_vals = myvals[item:item+max_list_num]
            grouped_lists[counter].extend(nested_vals)
            counter += 1
    except IndexError: pass
    return grouped_lists
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
mylist = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7',
          'item8', 'item9', 'item10', 'item11', 'item12', 'item13', 'item14',
          'item15', 'item16', 'item17', 'item18', 'item19', 'item12']
max_list_num = 4
print([mylist[i:i+max_list_num] for i in range(0, len(mylist), max_list_num)])
```

**Output:**

```
[['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'], ['item5', 'item6', 'item7', 'item8'], ['item9', 'item10', 'item11', 'item12'], ['item13', 'item14', 'item15', 'item16'], ['item17', 'item18', 'item19', 'item12']]
```